# Glue trigger cannot create EVENT trigger

Tags: aws-glue, aws-event-bridge

I want to create glue trigger EVENT type. I do not have such option in console, when I try same with aws cli I am getting an error.

With command:

```
aws glue create-trigger --workflow-name test --type EVENT --name test  --actions JobName=test

An error occurred (EntityNotFoundException) when calling the CreateTrigger operation: Entity not found
```

test glue job exists, same error I get when I try other trigger type.

With command:

```
aws glue create-trigger --type EVENT --name test  --actions JobName=test

An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateTrigger operation: Workflow name cannot be null or empty
```

But when I change trigger type it creates trigger.

Anyone has any idea what might be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Event triggers, they would need to be associated with a Glue workflow. First create a workflow using

```
aws glue create-workflow --name test-workflow
```

The second command is missing the --workflow-name. the trigger needs to be added to a workflow and executed after the workflow is created.
`aws glue create-trigger --name test-trigger --type EVENT --workflow-name test-workflow  --actions JobName=test`

Comment: It worked. I did not realised glue workflow and job are two separate things.